# How to execute php function in the same file with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm reading some tutorials on the net because I've never worked with ajax and mainly what I'm trying to get is this:

I have a php file in which I have two functions `create()` and `population()`.
The function created contains the following form:

**main.php**

```
function create()
{
    echo "
    <form action='#' method='post'>
        Name <input type='text' name='nome'>
        Col <input type='text' name='colore'>
        Plan <select name='planning'><option value='p1'>p1</option></select>
        <input type='button' value='inserisci' name='inserisci'>
        <input type='button' value='register' name=register'
    </form>";
}
```

this function is called in another php file like this:

**settings.php**

```
//some stuff html
<?php require_once('main.php');
   create();
?>
//other stuff
```

and I need to display the form with the relevant fields to be filled.

The function `population` function instead taken the data of this form and place them in a database. So far no problem.
What I'm trying to do, and for this I ask you about a few examples, to perform the function population when the `"register"` in the form is pressed (so we would have to recognize also the button down).
The `population` function must be performed with a ajax request because I do not want to reload the page. But are in high tide and not have the faintest idea how to do this, I'd like to learn why in the future I will have to do with this technology.

**NB:**

The form is displayed into settings.php but the population function is available in main.php, the `population` function is a simple query for the database..

Thanks.

Comment: Its best to make distinct files for the ajax to call rather than calling the same file with ajax. You'll end up with a ton of spaghetti code otherwise that down the road you'll wish you had done different.

Comment: Aside from that general caution: I can't tell from your question what you're actually trying to do. So that was based only on the question title.

Comment: I need to know if is possible do this in my idea.

Comment: If you put your functions in one file that you include in others when you need to call them, and you had one file that the ajax called which includes that functions file and calls the function, sure (but to do it all in one file would require if-statements checking parameters)

Comment: The Ajax call will need to POST/GET the data to the relevant php file. Here php can pick up the variables and call whatever functions that you need to process your data.

Comment: The data are taken from the form displayed in the settings.php, so basically should be created a function for check which button was pressed and put inside the ajax request.

Comment: In the ajax section there is a downvote joker. Anyway interesting question.

Answer (score -1):

Use something to check when your button is pushed, so for example:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false; sendForm();" value="submit" />
```

After pushing this button, the following function will fire (javascript function).

```
function sendForm() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("formHolder").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("POST", "main.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Which will send an AJAX request in the background to main.php to fix the form data. After this it will be put in the `<div id="formHolder"></div>` in this example.